# How to find Center of Gravity of the shape in the Image (Bitmap)

Tags: java, android, image

Here is my work I'm trying to find the center of gravity of the shape in the image (bitmap) using the selected coordinate of the image:

```
float xpos = 0f , ypos = 0f;
PointF currF = new PointF();
for (PointF pointF : pointFArrayList){
     xpos += pointF.x;
     pos += pointF.y;
} 
currF.x = xpos/pointFArrayList.size();
currF.y = ypos/pointFArrayList.size();
addRoundIconToViewRed(currF); //Marking the center of gravity
```

As an example, see this image:

[image: use this image to find COG]

Comment: Do you want to get the center of gravity of the image or the shape in the image?

Comment: I want to get the center of gravity of the shape in the Image

Comment: How do you obtain the shape from the image? Are you doing any image processing?

Comment: I am drawing the shape on the image using onDraw method and after selection creating a new bitmap using createBitmap method

public void cropImage() {

        Log.e(TAG, "height width " + lineView.getWidth() + "  " + lineView.getHeight());
        Bitmap fullScreenBitmap =
                Bitmap.createBitmap(lineView.getWidth(), lineView.getHeight(), src.getConfig());

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(fullScreenBitmap);
    }

Comment: are you looking for an algorithm on how to calculate the center of gravity or do you need help analyzing the pixels of your image?

Answer (score 0):

1.First the bitmap set to image view

2.get center point for that particular image view

```
     centreX=imageView.getX() + imageView.getWidth()  / 2;
     centreY=imageView.getY() + imageView.getHeight() / 2;
```

Comment: It will return ImageView Center point, not the center of gravity